# Multiple subdomains for Amazon S3 Bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, subdomain

We are white labelling site so that mysite.com and site.com and site2.com all share the same code base but different front end UI. They use a lot of the same images, including product images, which are hosted on Amazon S3. The s3 bucket name is based off site.com such that the host is:

`https://siteDOTcom-new.s3.amazonaws.com/`

Now, we don't care what the Amazon S3 url looks like but some clients do, so we're trying to figure out how to do it. We've tried CNAMEs but that didn't work out. Is it possible to have multiple subdomain aliases for the same S3 bucket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into Amazon Cloudfront for two reasons:

1. It would allow you to point to the same s3 buckets with different URLs (e.g. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html)
2. As a CDN, it will give better downloading speeds for people using your site

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; I'll definitely look into it.

Comment: My bounty expires in a day so I'm going to award it to you even though I haven't had a chance yet to really look into it. Thanks for your input however :).